# define a HDFS file on Elastic MapReduce on Amazon Web Services

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I'm starting the implementation of the KMeans algorithm on the Hadoop MapReduce framework. I'm using in this regard the elastic MapReduce offered by Amazon Web Services. I want to create an HDFS file to save on it the initial cluster coordinates, and to store on it the final results of the reducers. I'm totally confused here. Is there anyway to create or "upload" this file into the HDFS format in order to be seen by all the mapper.

Any clarification in this regard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I got how to do it. 
So, in order to upload the HDFS file into the cluster. You have to connect to your cluster via putty (by using the security key).

Then write these commands

hadoop distcp s3://bucke_name/data/fileNameinS3Bucket HDFSfileName

with 
fileNameinS3Bucket is the name of the file in the s3 bucket
HDFSfileName is what do you want to name your file when I uploaded.

To check if the file has been uploaded
hadoop fs -ls